# How do you get Quickbooks budget data

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I can't seem to find a way to get QuickBooks Budget data. Is budget data available and if not, any ideas of when it will be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Budget entity is not yet available in the QBO v3 api and is not in the roadmap yet. Will pass the feedback.